# Jquery Responsive Content Slider with Independent Movements

Tags: jquery, slider

I noticed this content slider today on a site featured on awwwards.com:

http://www.humaan.com.au/

i'm looking for either a free or premium plugin that can mimic very similar behaviour.

**I need**
Responsive and 100% width.
Has independent elements / movement

Any ideas fully apreciated, as i cant find much on the usual "top 50/100 content slider" google searches.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/2580848